# Laravel, return view with Request::old

Tags: validation, laravel

fHello, for example, i have simple input field (page index.php)

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{Request::old('name')}}">
```

In controller

```
$this->validate($request, ['name' => 'required']);
```

After this, i want make some check without Laravels rules. For example

```
if($request['name'] != 'Adam') { return view('index.php'); }
```

But after redirect, Request::old is empty. How to redirect to index.php and save old inputs and use Request::old, or its impossible? Thank you.

PS its example, i know that Laravel has special rules for check inputs value

Comment: In the view you can also use `value="{{ old('name') }}"`

Answer (score 31):

Old question, but for future reference, you can return the input to a view by flashing the request input just beforehand.

i.e.

```
session()->flashInput($request->input());

return view('index.php');
```

then in your view you can use the helper

```
{{ old('name') }}
```

or

```
{{Request::old('name')}}
```

Comment: Thank you for adding your answer!

Comment: You saved my day ... Problem was solved by ... session()->flashInput(session('DATA'))

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel 8.x, you can simply use `$request->flash();`

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#flashing-input-to-the-session

Answer (score 3):

You can use back() instead if any url. These function helps you in any case to be able to return to previous page without writing route.

```
return back()->withInput();
```

Comment: Can you edit your proposed answer to expand on what this does and how it addresses the OP?

Answer (score -3):

To add the input to your request try adding:

```
return view('index.php')->withInput();
```

Comment: this doesnt work, it works for redirects, but not for views somehow